# typescript: a component must have open()

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm making modal component which controlled by redux so I inject a modal component's ref by dispatching an `SET_MODAL` so modal component can be changed by using it.

```js
dispatch(setModal(modalComponentRef));

// reducer
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === "SET_MODAL") {
      return {
        ...state,
        modal: action.payload.modal,
      }
    }
}
```

And then call modal component by dispatching an action `SHOW_MODAL`

```js
const onOpen = () => { ... }
dispatch(showModal(onOpen));
```

```js
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "SHOW_MODAL") {
    return state.modal.open(action.payload.onOpen);
  }
}
```

modal component should open by calling its function `open()`

```js
const Modal = (props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const open = (onOpen) => {
     setIsOpen(true);
     onOpen();
  }
  return {
    isOpen && (
      <div>
        // ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In this case I want to force react component must have `open: () => void` how to do it by defining type definition?

```js
// modalComponentRef must have open()
dispatch(setModal(modalComponentRef));
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you're trying to do. In the example component you showed, `open` is a local variable. Are you trying to enforce that the function must instantiate a local variable named `open`? If so, typescript has no way to do that. There's also no way you could interact with that function externally, since it's a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enforce that the argument passed to `setModal()` must have `.open()` method, the constraint should be placed inside `setModal`'s function signature.

```
function setModal<T extends { open(): void }>(ref: T): { type: string, action: { modal: T } }
```